# Refine Using Awk or Sed with Curl

Tags: curl, sed, awk

I have a file url that outputs like:

```
//
data = {
    'ip': '',
    'server_ip': '',
    'router_name': 'Banana Hammock',
    'wan_domain': '',
    'wan_gateway': '74.125.224.32',
    'wan_gateway_get': '74.125.224.32',
    'wan_get_domain': 'isp.example.com',
    'wan_hostname': 'MumbaVille',
    'wan_hwaddr': '00:00:00:00:00:00',
```

I'm using this command to get wan_gateway_get:

```
curl -k http://mumbarouter.com/get.asp?statits | awk '/wan_gateway_get/ {print $2}'
```

which outputs:

```
'74.125.224.32',
=
```

How can I make it output just:

```
74.125.224.32
```

Thank you, and happy mumba!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Make it easy on yourself](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=FLlBzu2LRPA#t=51s) ... cause breaking up is so very *easy* to do:

```
curl -k http://mumbarouter.com/get.asp\?statits |
  awk -F\' '/wan_gateway_get/ {print $4}'
```

Comment: @reinierpost, thank you, that works too — how to pick winner? flip coin?

Answer (score 1):

The following

```
awk '/wan_gateway_get/ {match($2, "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"); print substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

is one of the possible way.

Comment: i can't decide who to pick for winner? we could all flip coin.

Comment: his one is shorter and clearer and has less reputations, so I would pick his one; but it is up to you of course

Comment: okay, i will go with your advice — thanks very much, and have a great day sir!

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/) solution: free-form parsing of the actual syntax. (Mandatory closing brace added to example data.)

```
@(define comment)//@nil@\n@(end)
@(define ws)@(cases)@(comment)@(or)@/\s*/@(end)@(end)
@(define id (id))@(ws)@{id /\w[\w\d_]+/}@(ws)@(end)
@(define item (it))@(ws)'@{it /[^']+/}'@(ws)@(end)
@(define braced_key_values (ithash))@\
  {@(coll)@(item key):@(item value)@(until)}@(end)}@\
  @(bind ithash @(progn '#H((:equal-based) ,*[mapcar list key value])))@\
@(end)
@(freeform)
@(id config)@(ws)=@(ws)@(braced_key_values config-hash)
@(output)
wan_gateway in configuration "@config" is @[config-hash "wan_gateway"]
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr data.txr data.txt
wan_gateway in configuration "data" is 74.125.224.32
```